# Load method for class in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have written my custom class in Python. I would like to know how to create load and dump method for the class so that I could load the class object from serializable file and dump the class to serializable file. for e.g for in Keras you can save a model by calling load method on the model

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
model = Model()
model.load("sample_model.h5")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pickle

```
import pickle

# Example class
class Robot():
    def speak(self, name='Bob'):
        print('hello, my name is {name}.'.format(name=name))

r = Robot()

# Write
with open('robot.class', 'wb') as class_file:
    pickle.dump(r, class_file)

# Load
import pickle

with open('robot.class', 'rb') as config_dictionary_file:
    r = pickle.load(config_dictionary_file)
```

Please note that the definition of `Robot` class need to be loaded into namespace before loading the instance back.

Using similar method you can wrap a load function in your class to load like keras model

## From your comment, example:

```
import pickle

# Example class
class _data():
    test='Bob'

class Robot():
    r = _data()

    def load(self, file_name='robot.class'):
        with open('robot.class', 'rb') as class_file:
            self.r = pickle.load(class_file)

    def save(self, file_name='robot.class'):
        with open('robot.class', 'wb') as class_file:
            pickle.dump(self.r, class_file)

    def speak(self):
        print('hello, my name is {name}.'.format(name=self.r.test))

r = Robot()
r.r.test = 'John'
r.save()

del r

r = Robot()
r.load()
r.speak()
```

Comment: yes i am aware about pickle but I want to know about if I can have class method which can load the class for example something like this

```class Robot():
    def speak(self, name='Bob'):
        print('hello, my name is {name}.'.format(name=name))
    def load(self, file_name)
          # functionality to load the same
rob = Robot()
rob.load("robot.class")
```

Comment: The load method in keras model just load the data it need from binary then get what it need, you dont need to load the Model class itself, like in your class, have a variable of internal class

Comment: @HuzaifaCalcuttawala is the edit what you need, added example, dont know your exact usecase so I provided a general idea example one.